# Record of debates at the state level

Tags: united-states

Not sure it is the right place to ask this question. Feel free to migrate if appropriate.

Suppose there is a piece of state legislation I am interested in. Is there an easy way to obtain a record of the debates that led to its adoption?

**For instance :** I would like to know what motivated legislators to adopt https://www.tncourts.gov/rules/rules-civil-procedure/4703 and in particular Rule 47.03, amended by order filed February 1, 1995, effective July 1, 1995; and by order filed January 31, 2003, effective July 1, 2003.

Any chance I could easily

1. get my hand on some material explaining the motivation for the rule and its two amendements?
2. Find out what the two amendements changed with respect to the rule formerly in place?